# VS Code lightning Explorer not rendering anymore

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

This used to work for me. I tried re-installing the extension pack and nothing. Maybe somebody else is having the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They just appeared. No action necessary - Maybe just a reboot?

[image]

Comment: This happened again a couple of times. Not sure if it is just the plugin freaking out... Ususally a PC restart is what does it.